# Finding shortest path in 2d array

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path

I need to find the shortest path from top left to bottom right.

The Rules are it has to go from **A** to **B** to **A** to **B** etc.

See picture as example:

[image]

The expected output for the above picture is then **13**.

I'm trying to implement this in java with a dijkstra algorithm for this but then got stuck. Is this the right way to go?

Comment: Does this needs to be implemented over an image? @David

Comment: [Dijsktra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for sure is one way to tackle the problem (another feasible algorithm migth be [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)). You should tell us where exactly you are stuck (if it's a code issue then show the code you've got so far) but I guess it's with the layout of the graph. Basically you could assume that if two adjacent cells have the same value there's a "wall" between them, so graph's edges can only be between adjacent cells with different values.

Comment: I'm trying to implement it in Java

Comment: Just implement [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Comment: So what have you tried? There are many pages regarding this topic. https://www.baeldung.com/java-dijkstra

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55239386/finding-shortest-path-in-two-dimensional-array-javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to find the shortest path from the top left corner to the bottom right corner (or between any arbitrary 2 points), dijsktra is one possible way to go, however you must correctly construct a graph from the input.

In this case I would go for a simple `flood-fill` algorithm. You can find several online resources explaining it including [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0XFafeGjsI) or [this article](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/flood-fill-algorithm/tutorial/), so I won't go in more details in this answer.

You can find the shortest route using only 2 matrices (one for your original array of letter and one for the distances) if you implement your rules correctly (A to B and B to A only).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any graph traversal algorithm or any pathfinding algorithm. T, here are a lot of algorithms such as A*, Dijekstra, BFS, DFS ...

For example, let's take BFS, which finds the shortest path between 2 nodes of the graph. Suppose, your 2d array is a graph, where edges are on condition if the distance between 2 nodes is 1 and one of the nodes is A and second one is B. Read mode about BFS here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

Just construct the graph from your matrix and implement BFS for the graph, or you can simply implement BFS for the array.